# Is it possible to separate air return vents when you have 2 different furnaces?

Tags: hvac

I have 2 separate furnaces, one for basement suite and another one for upstairs. The tenant in basement suite smokes and I smell the cigarette smoke upstairs through the vents... how is that possible if we are supposed to have to different air systems? I asked the technician, he said we are sharing the return air vent, what the heck!! 
My question: is it possible to have 2 different air return vents? how the tenant in the basement suite can have his/her own air system without sharing?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Where are the furnaces located?

Comment: Does the inter-unit separation have any ratings, or is it an unrated interior assembly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Both either should not be from the same room and/or the room should be very large and can pull make-up air from elsewhere.